# How can I change the Script package in Atom to run code using Scheme instead of Guile?

Tags: scheme, lisp, editor, atom-editor

I'm coding in Scheme using Atom on OSX, and I want to be able to run my code using the Script package - specifically, using MIT:GNU Scheme, rather than `guile`, as `guile` gives no output. Alternatively, making it so guile outputs the line-by-line output of my script would also work, as right now it just shows the runtime.

I made a script called `atom-scheme` and put it in `/usr/local/bin`, which does the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

atom-scheme () {
    scheme --quiet < "$1"
}
```

`scheme` is the alias I made to the `mit-scheme` script that comes with a download of MIT/GNU Scheme.

I've already tried editing ~/.atom/packages/script/lib/grammars/lisp.coffee, replacing "guile" on lines 32 and 35 with "atom-scheme", however, in doing so I get a TypeError in Atom's BufferedProcess class.

I want the result to be that the window that pops up when I run code using guile is where I can see the line-by-line output of the code. However, what ends up happening is the following.

(stack trace below)

**Atom**: 1.40.1 x64
**Electron**: 3.1.10
**OS**: Mac OS X 10.14.6
**Thrown From**: [script](https://github.com/rgbkrk/atom-script) package 3.18.1

#### Stack Trace

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setEncoding' of undefined

```
At /Applications/Atom.app/Contents/Resources/app/static/<embedded>:14

TypeError: Cannot read property 'setEncoding' of undefined
    at BufferedProcess.bufferStream (/Applications/Atom.app/Contents/Resources/app/static/<embedded>:14:1127503)
    at BufferedProcess.handleEvents (/Applications/Atom.app/Contents/Resources/app/static/<embedded>:14:1129015)
    at BufferedProcess.start (/Applications/Atom.app/Contents/Resources/app/static/<embedded>:14:1127023)
    at new BufferedProcess (/Applications/Atom.app/Contents/Resources/app/static/<embedded>:14:1126771)
    at Runner.run (/packages/script/lib/runner.js:32:28)
    at Runtime.execute (/packages/script/lib/runtime.js:78:17)
    at HTMLElement.scriptRun (/packages/script/lib/script.js:98:40)
    at CommandRegistry.handleCommandEvent (/Applications/Atom.app/Contents/Resources/app/static/<embedded>:11:349123)
    at KeymapManager.dispatchCommandEvent (/Applications/Atom.app/Contents/Resources/app/static/<embedded>:11:1249835)
    at KeymapManager.handleKeyboardEvent (/Applications/Atom.app/Contents/Resources/app/static/<embedded>:11:1245969)
    at WindowEventHandler.handleDocumentKeyEvent (/Applications/Atom.app/Contents/Resources/app/static/<embedded>:11:284329)
```

#### Commands

```
     -0:02.7.0 script:run (input.hidden-input)
```

#### Non-Core Packages

```
activate-power-mode 2.7.0 
atom-clock 0.1.17 
atom-ide-ui 0.13.0 
autocomplete-python 1.16.0 
autocomplete-swift 1.0.3 
go-plus 6.1.0 
Hydrogen 2.12.0 
ide-rust 0.21.0 
language-asymptote 1.1.0 
language-boo 0.1.0 
language-julia 0.19.1 
language-kotlin 0.5.0 
language-lisp 0.2.0 
language-markdown 0.37.0 
language-pseudo 0.1.3 
language-r 0.4.2 
language-racket 0.4.0 
language-rockstar 0.3.1 
language-rust 0.4.12 
language-scheme 1.4.0 
language-swift 0.5.0 
language-x86-64-assembly 2.2.11 
python-tools 0.6.9 
script 3.18.1 
swift-debugger 0.1.2 
teletype 0.13.4
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Guile is Scheme. You can use other Scheme *implementation* if you like, but as far as I know - there is no Scheme implementation called scheme. So there is no point in changing from `guile` to `scheme`. On the other hand, error message is says it can't set undefined encoding, so maybe all you need now is to set encoding at the top of your scheme file: `;; -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-` ?

Comment: rsm, You're right, I was unclear. I linked scheme to a script I put in /usr/local/bin which runs scheme using the mit/gnu scheme version 10.1.0. Editing now to reflect this, and then I'll try your encoding trick. EDIT: Nope, putting that line at the top didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

That script doesn't actually run anything: it just defines a shell function which then is lost as soon as the script terminates.  You're probably then getting errors because the subprocess has exited.  You probably actually want to run a Scheme.  For instance:

```
#!/bin/sh -
exec scheme --quiet < "$1"
```

Or whatever it is you want to do (which is not, in fact, this).

More generally you either need to change your wrapper so it agrees with the command lines generated by [`lisp.coffee`](https://github.com/rgbkrk/atom-script/blob/master/lib/grammars/lisp.coffee), or change `lisp.coffee` so it generates the appropriate command line for your script.  Neither your original script nor my modification to it do that.

A good approach to debug this is to write a script which does something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh -

echo "$(date)": "$@" >> /tmp/my.debugging.file
env >> /tmp/my.debugging.file
```

And then let the editor run it.  Now you know, or at least have an idea, what arguments you need to implement.

Based on comments it looks like the script is not being found.  There are two probable causes of this:

- it's in `PATH` but it's not executable;
- it's not in `PATH`, either becaus the editor's `PATH` is not what you think or because `PATH` is somehow otherwise wrong.

For the first of these the solution is `chmod +x .../atom-scheme`, where `...` means 'the directory it's in'.

For the second of these: it is mysterious to me how `PATH` gets set for GUI applications on OSX: as far as I know they're not children of a login shell in the traditional Unix sense, so setting `PATH` in shell init files in the traditional way probably does not work: they're children of *some* login process, but I don't understand how that process determines what `PATH` should be.

You can determine what `PATH` *is* for the editor by replacing the invocation of the script by an invocation of `env`: this will print the environment and amongst it will be `PATH`.  If it's wrong I don't know how to make it right however: perhaps some OSX person can help there.

Comment: Changed the script. Same issue, same stack trace.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you need to either change your script to do what `guile` does (ie to accept a `-c` options &c &c) or modify `grammars.coffee` to create the command line you need.  See v2 of my answer.

Comment: Did you mean lisp.coffee? I can't find a grammars.coffee file in script. Script only uses the -c option for line-by-line evaluation, so I don't think that's the issue.

Comment: I ran the changes you suggested to see the arguments, but I don't think it actually got around to running it - no data was written to the debug file.

Comment: As far as I can tell, Script only passes a filename to the command, as evidenced by lines 34-36 in lisp.coffee. Seeing as the script I had originally was geared to take a filename, I don't think that arguments are the issue here.

Comment: Yes, `lisp.coffee`, sorry.  There are at least two ways the command can be run: with a file or with a selection (via `-c` with `guile`).  However if the script is not being run at all then that's your problem: why isn't it?  If it in `PATH`? is it executable?  What happens if you replace it by, say `env` in the config?

Comment: I think you've narrowed it down! Replacing ```guile``` with ```env``` results in ```env``` running successfully when I hit CMD-I. I'll look at why Atom can't get at the script.

Comment: So I've narrowed it down to an issue with my atom-scheme file. I tried replacing `atom-scheme` with a bunch of things spread throughout my $PATH, and they all ran.

Comment: I've added some notes on that tot the end of the answer.  I suspect this might be becoming the sort of thing better debugged using some chat thing than a SE answer (I don't understand how the SE chat thing works though: I'm an IRC holdout).